# kendo tabstrip with ajax post method

Tags: asp.net, ajax, kendo-ui, tabs, strip

I realized the kendo UI Tabstrip (for ASP.NET MVC) uses the get method for ajax calls to load the content. but my viewmodel contains some lists and it cannot be sent via get method. how can I change the deafult ajax call method from get to post.

```
     @(Html.Kendo()
          .TabStrip().Name("productManagementTabStrip")
          .Items(items =>
           {
              items.Add()
                   .Text("Search Products")
                   .Encoded(false)
                   .LoadContentFrom("GetProductManagementSearchView", "Products", Model)
                   .Selected(true);}))
```

and my model is:

```
    public class ProductManagementSearchViewModel
    {
      public bool AutoSearch { get; set; }
      public string ProductNumber { get; set; }
      public string ProductDetailNumber { get; set; }
      public string ProductSupplier { get; set; }
      public string ProductTitleDescription { get; set; }
      public int? ProductCategotyTypeId { get; set; }
      public IList<int> ProductCategory { get; set; }
      public IList<int> ProductStatusIds { get; set; }
      public string ProductSupplierCode { get; set; }
      public string ProductProgramItemCode { get; set; }
      public ProductManagementSearchViewModel()
      {
        AutoSearch = false;
        ProductStatusIds = new List<int>();
        ProductCategory = new List<int>();
      }
    }
```

I checked the data sent to controller by Fiddler. All the model properties sent as query string. It's obvious the ajax call method is get. I have two arrays in the model. the URL is like that: /Products/GetProductManagementSearchView?ProductCategory=System.Collections.Gene‌​ric.List1[System.Int32]&ProductStatusIds=System.Collections.Generic.List1[Syste‌​m.Int32]&AutoSearch=False&_=1463491518221

I also sent the model as a RouteValueDictionary, but no any progress, Like new RouteValueDictionary(Model)

Comment: Hi Alireza, Welcome to SO. Kindly show us the efforts you did to solve your issue. What were the errors you got?

Comment: I checked the data sent to controller by Fiddler. All the model properties sent as query string. It's obvious the ajax call method is get. I have two arrays in the model. the URL is like that: /Products/GetProductManagementSearchView?ProductCategory=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]&ProductStatusIds=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]&AutoSearch=False&_=1463491518221

Comment: I sent the model as a RouteValueDictionary, but no any progress. new RouteValueDictionary(Model)

Comment: Alireza, please edit **your question** with this relevant information.